# Data output is duplicated in javascript. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Why is the data in the cycle is duplicated each time you update (after 5 seconds).
displayed:

> 2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN SZ SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:37:03 WARN SZ SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN SZ SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:37:03 WARN SZ SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075

I need without doubles:

> 2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN SZ SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:37:03 WARN SZ SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075
>   2016-09-09 09:12:18 WARN MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075

The HTML:

```
<ul></ul>
```

The script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */
    $.getJSON('api2.php', function(data) {
        /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            $('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.first_name + ' ' + val.last_name + ' ' + val.email + ' ' + val.age + '</li>');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Output from api2.php:

```
[{"date":"2016-09-09 09:12:18","event":"WARN ","region":"SZ","host":"SIU05","type":"[main]","info":"Started, locked port 7075"},{"date":"2016-09-09 09:37:03","event":"WARN ","region":"SZ","host":"SIU05","type":"[main]","info":"Started, locked port 7075"},{"date":"2016-09-09 09:12:18","event":"WARN ","region":"MRP","host":"SIU05","type":"[main]","info":"Started, locked port 7075"},{"date":"2016-09-09 09:12:18","event":"WARN ","region":"MRP","host":"SIU05","type":"[main]","info":"Started, locked port 7075"},{"date":"2016-09-09 09:12:18","event":"WARN ","region":"MRP","host":"SIU05","type":"[main]","info":"Started, locked port 7075"},{"date":"2016-09-09 09:12:18","event":"WARN ","region":"MRP","host":"SIU05","type":"[main]","info":"Started, locked port 7075"},{"date":"2016-09-09 09:12:18","event":"WARN ","region":"MRP","host":"SIU05","type":"[main]","info":"Started, locked port 7075"},{"date":"2016-09-09 09:12:18","event":"WARN ","region":"MRP","host":"SIU05","type":"[main]","info":"Started, locked port 7075"},{"date":"2016-09-09 09:12:18","event":"WARN ","region":"MRP","host":"SIU05","type":"[main]","info":"Started, locked port 7075"},{"date":"2016-09-09 09:12:18","event":"WARN ","region":"MRP","host":"SIU05","type":"[main]","info":"Started, locked port 7075"},{"date":"2016-09-09 09:12:18","event":"WARN ","region":"MRP","host":"SIU05","type":"[main]","info":"Started, locked port 7075"},{"date":"2016-09-09 09:12:18","event":"WARN ","region":"MRP","host":"SIU05","type":"[main]","info":"Started, locked port 7075"}]
```

Comment: is that output from api2.php?

Comment: Added api2.php above conclusion in question

Comment: Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ashishbpatil1/Lx3ro9o1/) . It is showing output like you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add `$('ul').empty();`

```
   function getData(){
                    $.getJSON('api.php', function(data) {
                            $('ul').empty();
                            /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
                            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                                    $('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.date + ' ' + val.event + ' ' + val.region + ' ' + val.host + ' '+ val.type + ' ' + val.info + '</li>');
                });
                setTimeout(getData, 5000);
                });
                }
```